# Menus disappeared in ubuntu 16.04

Tags: 16.04

I installed Ubuntu 16.04 one week ago.
Everything fine! I used it the whole week for work.

from today (29-May 2016) the menus from various programs disappeared.
As far as I tried the programs are: Gimp, Inkscape, LibreOffice, DocumentViewer, Geeqie, Agave, PdfShuffler,Shotwell,

while Scribus, Blender, FreeCad, (the proprietary) DraftSight and the browsers Chrome and Firefox as well as Thunderbird have no problems.

Unfortunately Yesterday I used only the programs that work well, so I am not able to say if this problems came up with the updates from yesterday (28 May) or from today (29.May)

Anyway I need urgently help, I use this computer for work!
Any suggestions what I can do????

Comment: Please update your question with the output of `tail -n 40 /var/log/apt/history.log`.

Comment: Known bug, allegedly a fix was released just now: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/bamf/+bug/1532226

Answer (score 0):

Output of `tail -n 40 /var/log/apt/history.log`:

> cannot open '/var/log/apt/history.log.' for reading: No such file or directory

Anyway, searching in other forums I found out. that many users had this problem.

The solution was: `restart unity-panel-service`

I still wonder, why a simple reboot was not enough.